# Render JSON as response in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, flash, render, passport.js

I have been using NodeJS to create a REST API service. I don't need to render any webpages or 'ejs' files.

With that In mind I need to know if there is an arquitecture to save JSON templates like the 'views' folder for storing '.ejs' templates to use them as response for let's say a profile.

Also, I have been working with passport module to authenticate users and I cannot pass the flash message to a JSON response, so far this is how it looks:

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameFiled : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, function(req, res, password, done){
    User.findOne({'email' : email}, function(err, user){
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (user)
            return done(null, false, {message : 'Email already in use'});
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function(err, result){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            return done(null, newUser);
        });
    });

})) ;
```

And this is my routing :

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
    successRedirect : '/me',
    failureRedirect : '/loginerr',
    failerFlash : true
}));

/*===== SECURE ==== */

app.get('/me', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('Welcome user');
});

/* ========== Errors ====================== */

app.get('/loginerr', function(req, res, next){
    var message = req.flash('error');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({'error' : 'email already taken'});  //Here i should use the flash message instead.
});
```

As you can see, if there is an error when the user signs up, it is redirected to a /loginerr get, Instead of that i want to respond with a template of a JSON to respond with the flash message.

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can need use JSON.stringify()

for example

```
app.get('/loginerr', function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(`{error:${req.flash('error')}}`)
});
```

**Good Luck**